# JSON.parse is not a function in node js

Tags: node.js

I'm new in node js and I'm trying to parse a JSON. This is what I've done so far:

```
const JSON = require("nodemon/lib/utils");
...
someFunction() {
let sens = [];
// sensor is the result of fs.readFileSync call and file is a json array
sens = JSON.parse(sensors);
```

It throws me:

> JSON.parse is not a function.

How can I solve it?

Comment: why are you importing `const JSON = require("nodemon/lib/utils");`?

Comment: this is was suggest me by my IDE, is it wrong? Why downvote?

Comment: you do not need to importing. JSON is supported by node

Comment: [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is a standard JavaScript function supported by Node.js. You overwrite the `JSON` object in your first statement and this is why it doesn't work.

Comment: As an aside, don't blindly follow what your IDE tells you to do. Try to understand *why* it suggests something and *what* the consequences will be.

Comment: @GJCode Thanks for asking. This helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just comment out the very first line. `JSON` is built in already.

```
//const JSON = require("nodemon/lib/utils");
```

Comment: Or remove it entirely, for that matter.

Comment: thanks, as I said I'm new in node so I didn't know it and nobody had my same problem in this network,  so I don't know why downvote....

Comment: @GJCode Just a little tip, pretty much anything you can do in JavaScript, you can do in Node since it's built on Chrome's JavaScript engine.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is kind of a global object. It doesn't need to be required. So, just remove the line where JSON is required and it'll work fine.